# How to get unique values from multiple-column values in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have a query result using the `group_concat` function in MySQL like below.

| stf_invld_a | stf_invld_b | stf_invld_c | stf_invld_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21,22,0,0 | 21,23,25,0 | 21,24,25,0 | 24,26,27,0 |

Now I need a query where each column value will get only once, zero values will be skipped, and need another column with unique values.

| stf_invld_a | stf_invld_b | stf_invld_c | stf_invld_d | stf_invld |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21,22 | 23,25 | 24 | 26,27 | 21,22,23,24,25,26,27 |

Comment: Maybe consider adding sample data from the actual original table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right, here I'm using sample data for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, you should use `GROUP_CONCAT` along with `DISTINCT` and a `CASE` expression.  Something like:

```sql
SELECT  -- certain columns which appear in GROUP BY
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a != 0 THEN a END) AS stf_invld_a
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY -- certain columns
```